# Apache2 httpd run script on each request for reverse proxy

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, httpd.conf

I have an httpd container setup to be a reverse proxy. That part is working fine. Now I want to run a script to inspect each request the proxy receives. I've looked at both using mod_actions (don't think this will work since GET is only supported if there are query string parameters) and mod_rewrite. I'm now trying with the latter, but can't figure out the right configuration to get this to work. Here's what I've tried.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ErrorLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-error.log"
    CustomLog "/var/log/apache2/proxy-access.log" common

    ScriptAlias /cgi-bin/ /usr/local/bin/

    ProxyRequests Off
    Options +ExecCGI
    SSLProxyEngine On
    SSLProxyCheckPeerCN on
    SSLProxyCheckPeerExpire on
    ProxyPass "/" "https://www.example.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://www.example.com/"
    
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /usr/local/bin/throttle.cgi

    <Location "/">
        AllowOverride None
        Options +ExecCGI
        Require all granted
    </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

The script itself is some python that will do some processing, inspect headers/query string/body and either allow or deny the request. What's the best way to achieve this?

Basically what I want is if a user requests "http://myproxy.com" or "http://myproxy.com/tasks" or any path/query string combo, I want to invoke the script, and if allowed, pass the request on to the defined proxy backend.

EDIT: Currently, with this configuration, the contents of the script file are just returned, it's not actually executed.